# MySQL - PHP: Calculate total hours in a day between multiple events

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I have this table named **time_track**:

```
+----+--------+---------------------+---------+
| id | emplid | ctimestamp          | eventid |
+----+--------+---------------------+---------+
| 1  | 13     | 2016-06-02 03:41:41 | 1       |
+----+--------+---------------------+---------+
| 2  | 13     | 2016-06-02 09:04:49 | 2       |
+----+--------+---------------------+---------+
| 3  | 13     | 2016-06-02 10:03:13 | 1       |
+----+--------+---------------------+---------+
| 4  | 13     | 2016-06-02 13:21:23 | 2       |
+----+--------+---------------------+---------+
```

where `eventid 1 = Start work` and `eventid 2 = Stop work`.

How can I calculate the hours of any given day taking into consideration that working hours are the total hours between all eventid's 1 and 2 - `WHERE emplid = 13 AND Year(ctimestamp) = 2016 and Month(ctimestamp) = 06 and Day(ctimestamp) = 02`

Comment: What do you mean by `total hours in a day`?  Do you just mean total hours between the two timestamps?

Comment: I think it's a timesheet - so Fred clocks in at 03:41 and works until 09:04 ... has a nap for an hour and clocks in again at 10:03 until 13:21 - so it's that cumulative amount. However, if it *is* being broken down by day a 21:00 -> 04:00 will cause problems as the given day will have a *stop work* event but no preceding *start work* event.

Comment: Is this a query that will be running frequently against the database such that query performance is critical? If so, are you willing to consider an alternate schema?  How are you planning to address edge conditions like those noted by @CD001 above or cases where there are unpaired end/start times (i.e. incomplete data)?

Comment: Just edited my answer : added a function to calculate the total hours.

Comment: @Devon I mean total working hours if 1 is start of work and 2 is end of work. Events 1 and 2 can occur many times in a day, so I want the total working hours

Comment: @CD001 while that is true, everyday all open events are closed on 12:00AM of which results to employee not clocking out. The company works only day time

Comment: @MikeBrant Performance is crucial. How I will address edge conditions, I will get back to you once im done

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also do it with PHP (instead of SQL) :

```
<?php
$data = array( array( "1","2016-06-02 03:41:41" ),
               array( "2","2016-06-02 09:04:49" ),
               array( "1","2016-06-02 10:03:13" ),
               array( "2","2016-06-02 13:21:23" )
             );
$hours = 0;
foreach ( $data as $row ) // PROCESS ALL ROWS FROM QUERY.
{ if ( $row[ 0 ] == "1" ) // IF CURRENT ROW IS START TIME
       $start = strtotime( $row[ 1 ] );
  else { $stop = strtotime( $row[ 1 ] ); // STOP TIME. CALCULATE.
         $hours += ( $stop - $start ) / 3600;
       }
}
echo $hours; // 8.6883333333333.
?>
```

You can round the result.

Copy-paste previous code in a file, save it as .PHP and open it in your browser. Feel free to change the sample data.

Edit : it's easier to call a function to calculate all the hours :

```
<?php

function total_hours ( $data )
{ $hours = 0;
  foreach ( $data as $row )
    if ( $row[ "eventid" ] == "1" )
         $start = strtotime( $row[ "ctimestamp" ] );
    else { $stop = strtotime( $row[ "ctimestamp" ] );
           $hours += ( $stop - $start ) / 3600;
         }
  return $hours;
}

$sample_data = array( array( "id"         => 1,
                             "emplid"     => 13,
                             "ctimestamp" => "2016-06-02 03:41:41",
                             "eventid"    => 1 ),
                      array( "id"         => 2,
                             "emplid"     => 13,
                             "ctimestamp" => "2016-06-02 09:04:49",
                             "eventid"    => 2 ),
                      array( "id"         => 3,
                             "emplid"     => 13,
                             "ctimestamp" => "2016-06-02 10:03:13",
                             "eventid"    => 1 ),
                      array( "id"         => 4,
                             "emplid"     => 13,
                             "ctimestamp" => "2016-06-02 13:21:23",
                             "eventid"    => 2 )
                    );
echo total_hours( $sample_data ); // 8.6883333333333.
?>
```

Call this function with the sql-result you get from the query as parameter (and replace the `foreach` by `while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array` ).

Answer (score 3):

Unlike SQL only answers below, it seams efficient to combine SQL and PHP for readability and performance. Moreover, PHP will allow you to code how to handle exceptions like missing or double data.

```
<?php
// Generate test data like it would be returned by a PDO::fetchAll(PDO:::FETCH_ASSOC) with
// SELECT * FROM time_track 
//    WHERE emplid = 13 AND Year(ctimestamp) = 2016 and Month(ctimestamp) = 06 and Day(ctimestamp) = 02 
//    ORDER BY ctimestamp
$logs[] = ['ctimestamp'=>'2016-06-02 03:41:41', 'eventid'=>1];
$logs[] = ['ctimestamp'=>'2016-06-02 09:04:49', 'eventid'=>2];
$logs[] = ['ctimestamp'=>'2016-06-02 10:03:13', 'eventid'=>1];
$logs[] = ['ctimestamp'=>'2016-06-02 13:21:23', 'eventid'=>2];

// Compute working time
$worktime = 0; // in seconds
foreach ($logs as $log) {
    if ($log['eventid'] == 1) {  // start work
        $startWork = $log['ctimestamp'];
    } else { // end work
        $endWork = $log['ctimestamp'];
        $worktime += strtotime($endWork) - strtotime($startWork);
    }
}
echo gmdate('H:i', $worktime); // seconds to hours:minutes
?>
```

Running code: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/jx8h-ztuy

Below is a tested refinement of the above code including database access and a loop.
Since you indicate performance is crucial, you may want to use `PDO::prepare()`

```
<pre>
<?php
class TimeLog {
    private $pdo;
    private $pdoStatement;

    // constructor: connect to database and prepare statement
    function __construct(){
        // adapt following constructor to your database configuartion
        $this->pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=utf8mb4', 'username', 'password'); 
        $this->pdoStatement = $this->pdo->prepare(
            'SELECT * FROM time_track 
                WHERE emplid = :emplid 
                AND DATE(ctimestamp) = :cdatestamp
                ORDER BY ctimestamp
        ');
    }

    // compute workTime for given employee and date
    function workTime($emplid, $cdatestamp) {
        // fetch from database, executing prepared statement
        $this->pdoStatement->execute([':emplid'=>$emplid, ':cdatestamp'=>$cdatestamp]);
        $logs = $this->pdoStatement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        // compute working time
        $worktime = 0; // in seconds
        foreach ($logs as $log) {
            if ($log['eventid'] == 1) {  // start work
            $startWork = $log['ctimestamp'];
            } else { // end work
                $endWork = $log['ctimestamp'];
                $worktime += strtotime($endWork) - strtotime($startWork);
            }
        }
        return gmdate('H:i', $worktime); // convert seconds to hours:minutes
    }
}

$timeLog = new Timelog(); // invoke constructor once

$emplid = 13; // example

// echo registration of last seven days
for ($date = strtotime('-7 days'); $date <= time(); $date += 24 * 3600) {
    // convert $date to YYYY-MM-DD format
    $cdatestamp = date('Y-m-d', $date); 
    // execute one SQL statement and return computed worktime
    $workTime = $timeLog->workTime($emplid, $cdatestamp); 
    // show result
    echo $cdatestamp, "\t", $workTime, "\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: You should provide some explanation along with code example.

Answer (score 2):

You have to self-join your table on itself in a subuery and get the min of eventid=2 that is greater than the eventid=1 and calculate the difference between these 2 records. In the outer query you sum up the differences by day of the eventid=1 timestamps:

```
select date(t3.ctimestamp), t3.emplid, sum(diff) / 60 as hours_worked
from
    (select t1.id, t1.ctimestamp, t1.emplid, min(t2.ctimestamp) as mintime, timestampdiff(minute,min(t2.ctimestamp), t1.ctimestamp) as diff 
     from yourtable t1
     inner join yourtable t2 on t1.ctimestamp<t2.ctimestamp
     where t1.eventid=1
           and t2.eventid=2
           and t1.emplid=13
           and t2.emplid=13
           and date(t1.ctimestamp)='2016-06-02' --may have checked out the next day, I do not know how you want to handle that
     group by t1.id, t1.ctimestamp, t1.emplid) t3
group by date(t3.ctimestamp)
```

In a live environment I would not base a solution on the id column having no gaps, even if it is an auto increment column. Usually there are gaps. You also need to decide what happens if you have orphan check in or check out events. My code assumes that each check in has a corresponding check out.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

You can group by year and month as well if you need to further separate your data.

```
select day(ctimestamp) as Day, hour(ctimestamp) as Hour, count(*) as Count
from MyTable
where ctimestamp between :date1 and :date2
group by day(ctimestamp), hour(ctimestamp)
```

Comment: You should provide some explanation to your approach.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to calculate difference between the timestamps for events of 1 and events of 2. This does assume that for any given day, there are only 2 events per empl_id and the the checkout time is within the same day (e.g., overnight hours will not show in this query). It is not a very robust solution, but I am unsure of the integrity of your data and the edge cases you need to handle.

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(t1.c_timestamp, t2.c_timestamp) / 3600 AS hourDiff
FROM time_track t1
INNER JOIN time_track t2 
ON (t2.id > t1.id AND t2.event_id = 2 AND t1.empl_id = t2.empl_id AND DAY(t2.c_timestamp) = DAY(t1.c_timestamp) AND MONTH(t2.c_timestamp) = MONTH(t1.c_timestamp) AND YEAR(t2.c_timestamp) = YEAR(t1.c_timestamp))
WHERE t1.event_id = 1 AND t1.empl_id = 13 AND Year(t1.c_timestamp) = 2016 and Month(t1.c_timestamp) = 6 and Day(t1.c_timestamp) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

> SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2010-11-29 13:16:55') - UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2010-11-29 13:13:55') as output

`$entry_time` = [... get it here using query...]

`$exit_time` = [...get it here using query...]

$query = " `SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('` ".$entry_time." `') - UNIX_TIMESTAMP('` ".`$exit_time`." `') as days;`";

Comment: Why would one use SQL to subtract two PHP variables?

Comment: though it is php values, they **replace** *variable name* with *contents* (Here *content* is *timestamp*), on storing it into variable *$query* AS ** String **. then the value like

$query = SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(2010-11-29 13:16:55) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(2010-11-29 13:13:55) as days; 

will be stored in variable and this will be passed to sql! @PaulH

Comment: Yes, but why use SQL? Why not write PHP only: `$query = $exit_time - $entry_time`. Using SQL here is like taking a car to walk 2 meters or yards.

Comment: $ query  is in  the syntax of sql! not php! you can try it over :
[link](http://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php#PMAURL-1:server_sql.php?db=&table=&server=1&target=&token=980363bc0f366543e8c97c5bfbc166e9) if your php server(apache) is on! 
`
"SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(2010-11-29 13:16:55) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(2010-11-29 13:13:55)"
`
this results something as :
`
| OUTPUT  |
|180            | as a cell in single cell table: You can try it
@PaulH

Comment: Yes I can use SQL for a substraction and yes, $query contains an SQL string, but `$query = "SELECT 5 - 4";` is a PHP statement assigning a string containing an SQL statement to a PHP variable.

Comment: He had tagged question with `php` & `mysql`; and i just demonstrated how php can calculate Timestamp difference from sql platform, **after clearly** mentionong the **correct SQL query** format.

Comment: in the simple form, what i did is:
$ firstname = "JOHN";
$ lastname = "PETER";
echo  " his First name is : ' " .  $ firstname  . " ' and last name is : ' " . $ lastname ;
which results to : His First name is : 'JOHN' and last name is : 'PETER'

 (you might have cared the `quotes` in output)

Comment: On code:
 `...` includes the string which goes to SQL as parameter which should be inside ` "..." ` what i did is just appended variable name on correct point so that, its value). Same as php `echo's` to `html` php passes value to SQL; My ans will output :`SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2010-11-29 13:16:55') - UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2010-11-29 13:13:55') as output;` including quotes.remember i didnot put variable names inside quotes, therefore the values will be the thing stored in the string in `$query` (not var_names);   and one more thing, SQL also accept multiple statements seperated by semicolon;@PaulH

Answer (score -1):

> QUERY :`SELECT DATEDIFF('2010-10-08 18:23:13', '2010-09-21 21:40:36') AS days;`

$time_entry = [...] // find query and save out put to this variable

$time exit = [...] // find query and save out put to this variable

> $query = "`SELECT DATEDIFF('`". time_entry ."`', '`".time_exit."`') AS days;`"

Comment: You should provide some explanation to your approach

Comment: though it is php values, they replace variable name with contents (Here content is timestamp), on storing it into variable $query AS ** String **. then the value like $query = SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(2010-11-29 13:16:55) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(2010-11-29 13:13:55) as days; will be stored in variable and this will be passed to sql! [ @MikeBrant ]